# How can I edit how many vertices are in my object?

Tags: vertices

I was watching a tutorial where someone could spawn a cylinder then type in how many vertices he wanted, it's an old tutorial and the ui doesn't show up on the left anymore.

Comment: You must be talking about the Operator box. In 2.8, once you've created your primitive object, you'll find this box in the bottom left. You can change the parameters as long as you don't edit or move the object.

Comment: It probably is collapsed and hard to see, but there's a small box on the lower left that you can expand to get all the options.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm talking about. I'm not quite sure where to find it, there's nothing in the bottom left.

Answer (score 1):

I know only one way to adjust **face count** of a model by sliding Ratio value of Decimate modifier in Collapse mode.

[image: Decimate modifier]